# how to get and include yahoo messenger API in asp.net(c#) project

Tags: api, yahoo-api, yahoo-pipes

how to get and include yahoo messenger API in  asp.net(c#) project.is there any idea for that

Answer (score 0):

you can start by reading the documentation at https://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/chapterintrotomessengersdk.html

Comment: but i cant understand how can i get API.please explain how to get API